# Python call via ssh different results than php shell_exec

Tags: php, python, ssh

I am calling the same python script via ssh and php shell_exec and getting different results. I'm trying to download a file based on user input. In both ssh and php the script runs and ends up on the download url and the download button is clicked. However, the php version does not have the file in the specified directory.

PHP

```
shell_exec("python /home/ubuntu/selenium_crawler.py [three private parameters]");
```

SSH

```
"python /home/ubuntu/selenium_crawler.py [three private parameters]"
```

Python file

```
import sys
import re
import time

activate_this_file = "/home/ubuntu/env/bin/activate_this.py"
execfile(activate_this_file, dict(__file__=activate_this_file))

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import action_chains, keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


def selenium_crawler(argv):
    """ Crawler to login to an account and grab some urls """

    if not len(argv[0]) > 0 and not len(argv[1]) > 0:
        return "Missing argument, use format: python selenium_crawler.py username password";

    username = argv[0]
    password = argv[1]
    page_url = argv[2]
    login_url = "URL HERE"

    # Create browser
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    display.start()

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
      "download.default_directory": "/home/ubuntu/tmp/",
      "download.prompt_for_download": False,
      "download.directory_upgrade": True,
      "safebrowsing.enabled": True
    })

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

    login(driver, username, password, login_url)
    response = navigate(driver, page_url)
    get_link(driver)


def login(driver, username="", password="", login_url=""):
    """ Login using Selenium """

    # Open login page
    driver.get(login_url)
    print "Navigated to page %s" % driver.title

    driver.find_element_by_id("Username").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_id("Password").send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-save").click()

    print "Login was attempted"


def navigate(driver, url):
    """ Navigate to the given url """

    driver.get(url)

    print "Navigating to %s" % url

    print driver.current_url


def get_link(driver):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("removed for security reasons").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("removed for security reasons").click()

    time.sleep(10)
    print driver.current_url

    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("removed for security reasons")[0].click()
    time.sleep(3)
    print "Clicked download btn"
    print driver.current_url

if __name__ == "__main__":
    selenium_crawler(sys.argv[1:])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Small nitpick when doing selenium don't use `time.sleep` but use `driver.wait`

Comment: Did you tryied comparing PHP `shell_exec()` output with `exec()` output ? (for information, `exec()` takes in first parameter the command line in string format, and for second parameter an array that will be filled by all the output, each line being appending to the array items).